# CSS - Using :nth-child to select an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/weka/FQTyG/

I have a div. In that div is 4 input boxes with 4 boxes to the right of them. It's like "select correct answer" to the question. However, when I hover over one of them, it's suppose to show "Correct?" while the other 3 are marked red X.. and if they don't click and merely hover.. it will revert back to the original selected answer.

However... it's not doing that as you can see. I am using `:nth-child` as I figure .. after I hover out. Make ALL off the four answers "red" and then make the one answer still selected "green" soon after...

But I can't seem it to make it work... Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking for help with multiple aspects of how things are displayed. Create a css class for each "state" you want things to be in... `correct` and `incorrect` or something.

When the user does something you care about or the form changes, mark all as incorrect, and use jquery logic like you have to choose which needs to be `correct`. Just add/remove the classes when needed.

If you can clarify the specific point you have trouble with, I can help a bit more specifically.